# Маска для динамических полей input

Tags: javascript, jquery, inputmask

Есть блок, который создает 5 input элементов при нажатии на кнопку, в этих input элементах у меня должна быть маска для ввода. Использую jquery mask
Но, у меня не получается это реализовать 
p.s. код урезал, оставил только 1 input

```
<script>
    var count = 1;
    $('#add').click(function() {

    count++;
    var obj = document.getElementById('field')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
      divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+count);
      var rdiv = 'removeclass'+count;
    divtest.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="phone[]" id="phone('+ count +')" class="form-control" placeholder="+7 (___) ___ __ __">';
    $('#phone('+ count +')').mask("(999) 999-99-99");
    obj.appendChild(divtest);
})
   function remove_field(rid) {
       $('.removeclass'+rid).remove();
   }
    </script>
```

Comment: Так вы сначала элемент в DOM добавьте, а потом уже манипуляции с ним сделайте.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/96qn0btr/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count = 1;
$('#add').click(function() {

  count++;
  var obj = document.getElementById('field')
  var divtest = document.createElement("div");
  divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass" + count);
  var rdiv = 'removeclass' + count;
  divtest.innerHTML = `<input type="text" name="phone${count}" id="phone${count}" class="form-control" placeholder="+7 (___) ___ __ __">`;
  $(`<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>`).appendTo(divtest).on('click', removeInput);
  obj.appendChild(divtest);
  $('#phone' + count).mask("(999) 999-99-99");
})

function removeInput(event) {
  $(event.target).parent().remove();
}
```

```css
.form-group .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3rem;
  right: 1rem;
  color: red;
}

.form-group {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="field"></div>
<button id="add" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add phones</button>
```